# Error message 401.2: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis

i'm trying to deploy my asp.net web app into company server but i don't know which type of permission choose as the image follow.

[image]

My web.config authentication section is set to "None"

What i have to do to view my website ?
Thanks

Comment: That looks fine to me, unless the username/password are wrong.